# How do I retrieve links inside <a href> from a page and show on Rails page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

I have been given ASP and HTML files  which contain HTML and some JavaScript code. I have to write a Rails application which will retrieve links from those pages and show them in Rails views.

I am stuck. Will Nokogiri help?

Comment: Try adding some code to understand.

Comment: Yep, nokogiri is generally useful in this type of tasks

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do you need to account for JavaScript links? Is JavaScript being used to dynamically create the URLs? Nokogiri is great for parsing HTML but not JavaScript, so yes, Nokogiri will help unless your needs don't fit its capabilities. And, since you really told us nothing useful we can't give a useful detailed answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will.

```
# open and read your HTML file as Nokogiri::HTML document
doc = File.open("your_file.html") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }

# collect all links that have not empty href attribute
links = doc.css('a').map { |link| link['href'] }.reject { |link| link.blank? }
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Vasily Yudin. I will try this and will let you know if it works.

Comment: @mehtasuraj09 no problem ;)

Comment: Don't write `File.open("your_file.html") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }`. Simply using `Nokogiri::HTML(File.read("your_file.html"))` does the same more clearly.